# Jquery Flashlight Effect

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I am looking for a jQuery plugin or code that will allow me to create a sort of flashlight effect.  To clarify, I want some dark colored sections on a site that when hovered over with the cursor a sort of faded light area appears that allows the user to see underlying images.  Like shining a flashlight into the dark and moving it around.  If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be so awesome!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the resources I came across only work well for text elements on a plain background. Since you mentioned you want the effect over images as well, this is probably what you're looking for: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=62822

Note that this plugin does use `<canvas>` and does not perform well on IE.